# IIS forced https redirect causes 503 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, ssl, iis

I have a load balancing environment on AWS powered by Elastic Beanstalk. The SSL certificate is applied on the load balancer. To force https redirects, i have followed the accepted andswer in this post [Redirect to https through url rewrite in IIS within elastic beanstalk's load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791820/redirect-to-https-through-url-rewrite-in-iis-within-elastic-beanstalks-load-bal). These are the exact lines of code which i have written in web.config

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But this causes the environment health to become red within 5 minutes of publish and website starts giving 503 errors. If i remove them, then there are no errors. Kindly help me fix this menace so that https redirection is successful. In the first 5 mins after the publish, http requests are successfully redirected to https. Only after that 503 error starts coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ELB is reporting HTTP status code 503, it generally means that there are no healthy EC2 instances behind it.

See the ELB toubleshooting guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http503

So now the question is **why**?

Basically, your health check is failing.

In that snippet of code you pasted, you are forcing an HTTP to HTTPS redirect of all requests except for `healthcheck.html`. The idea is that this single exclusion should be your health check.

To resolve this issue:

1. Make sure you have a health check on your EC2 instance that returns 200 when hitting the EC2 instance directly via HTTP. The health check **must** return 200 otherwise the ELB will fail the check and your EC2 instance will be considered unhealthy.
2. Make sure your ELB-configured health check matches that EC2 instance health check path. Include a leading `/` at the start of the health check path.
3. Put the health check path in your `<rewrite>` rule, omitting the leading `/`. You may want to put a `^` at the start and a `$` at the end since it's a regex comparison.

If the value in the `<rewrite>` rule doesn't match the actual health check in your ELB, then your ELB will receive a HTTP to HTTPS redirect response, which is considered a failure.

Comment: Hi Matt, envurl/healthcheck.html returns 404 error even when environment is up. I have also tried to remove that line from the rule, still doesn't help.

Comment: So your problem is that `/healthcheck.html` is returning 404. You need a health check that returns 200. So (a) What is the proper health check on your EC2 instance? (b) Put that in your ELB configuration and (c) Put that in the `<rewrite>` rule.

Comment: I have adjusted by answer to better address the issue.

Comment: how can i know the health check url of my instance? i have looked in console, but couldn't find it

Comment: You need to build it into your web application. So you decide what it is. Basically, it needs to be some page that the ELB can connect to in order to verify if your application is working. Since you want to do the HTTPS redirect, the health check should not be a normally-accessed page. Ideally it would be a dedicated page. It can be a simple page that just returns a 200 status code. But you could perform DB connection checks, etc. inside it too if you want.

Comment: Hi. I have added a simple html page and now configuring the load balancer. The load balancer is also giving option to ping over https. So could i just do that and omit the healthcheck part from url rewrite?

Comment: No, because your EC2 instance is not accepting HTTPS connections.

Comment: I finally understood the whole concept. I also had to put ^ and $ at the beginning of the url. Now things are working like a charm. Without your help, i couldn't have figured out the sol. Thank you very much

Comment: hi again. If you don't mind, pls help me in another issue. With these rules, i am seeing 500 error when trying to login from external providers. Without them its working fine. What can be a possible workaround to force https redirects and allow external logins like fb, google plus

Comment: @It'satrap  If it's a new issue, ask it as a new SO question.

Comment: Thanks. I have posted a new question. You can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394576/http-500-error-on-forced-https-redirects-with-external-logins