# HTTP 500 error on forced HTTPS redirects with external logins

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, ssl, iis

I have a load balancing environment on AWS powered by Elastic Beanstalk. The SSL certificate is applied on the load balancer. To force https redirects, i have followed the accepted answer in this post [Redirect to https through url rewrite in IIS within elastic beanstalk's load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791820/redirect-to-https-through-url-rewrite-in-iis-within-elastic-beanstalks-load-bal). These are the exact lines of code which i have written in web.config

```
<rules>
<rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^healthcheck.html$" negate="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This is working perfectly for everything else apart from external logins. Whenever i try to login from external providers, it gives HTTP 500 error. If i remove these lines, then logins are working perfectly both on localhost and on AWS. Kindly help me get a solution so that i am able to force HTTPS redirects and successfully get external logins.

Another thing worth mentioning is that without forced redirects, external providers redirect to http version of the site, even when i request from the https version.

**Update**
The exact code i am using for facebook login is as below

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "xxx",                      // production values
            AppSecret = "xxx",

            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name",
            Scope = { "email" },
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                },
                OnApplyRedirect = OnApplyRedirectHttps
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is running into an issue where it thinks it's using HTTP, but in reality it's using HTTPS. This is due to the HTTPS-to-HTTP connection-swap that's happening from the ELB.

So, whenever your app is using the request URL, you need to look at the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

This header will tell your application whether HTTP or HTTPS was used to connect to the ELB.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html

As part of the external login redirect (to Facebook, Twitter, etc.), your app will very often attach a return URL. You need to ensure that URL is using HTTPS rather than HTTP.

Query the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to determine which is used and ensure your return URL has the proper protocol.

This is going to become a common theme in your app. Just get used to doing it this way.

**Update:**

For example, as per this SO article:

[change facebook redirect_uri web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158495/change-facebook-redirect-uri-web-api)

you will want to put the following code at the start of your `Startup.Auth.cs` file:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
  context.Request.Scheme = "https";
  return next();
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt. I have tried this, but still getting the same error. I have posted the exact code which i am using.

Comment: By debugging, is `OnApplyRedirectHttps` doing a proper proto change? What is the URL it is producing compared to what is in the facebook URL in your browser?

Comment: I tried debugging, but on localhost, the if condition is never true.

Comment: Then embed a proper header/value into your request during debugging.

Comment: I embedded the "X-Forwarded-Proto" header and saw the function of RedirectHttps method. The absolute uri of the scheme is same as what it was without it.

Comment: Does anything in this SO question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158495/change-facebook-redirect-uri-web-api

Comment: My previous code was updating the wrong url. You'll need to modify the embedded `return_url` param inside the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127416/discussion-between-its-a-trap-and-matt-houser).