# How to reduce SameSite cookie attribute back to None in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, csrf, samesite

In order to avoid CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) most browsers are (since late 2019) automatically considering that any cookie that does not explicitly define SameSite attribute will be considered as Lax, instead of None which was the previous default.

And more recently (Feb 2020, since Chrome 80) browsers are also ignoring cookies which define SameSite=None and are not secure.

How can I change my session cookies to be automatically changed to None (to keep my SSO integrations working) in my Web.config?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48829569/3061212

Answer (score 13):

**EDIT of 2020-08-03**: [Chrome 85 doesn't allow insecure SameSite=None cookies](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/chrome-85-deps-rems)
I've updated code accordingly: 1) only apply `SameSite=None` if connection is https; 2) only apply `Secure;` if connection is https; 3) remove `SameSite=None` if it's http and samesite was added by the attributes (rewrite rules)

**Original response**:

This is a pure web.config solution which:

- Defines that session cookies should be rendered with `SameSite=None`
- Appends `SameSite=None` to any cookie which does not explicitly defines SameSite attribute (using methods that work in all versions of framework, in the worst case if some attribute is not accepted you can just remove it)
- Appends `Secure` attribute to any cookie which is not yet secure (as long as it's https request)
- Removed `SameSite=None` if it was applied by previous rules and it's not valid due to lack of https

```xml
<!-- This sets ASP.NET_SessionId cookie to SameSite=None, 
avoiding the default of current frameworks which is LAX -->
<system.web>

<!-- in newer framework versions you have to change the samesite 
level like by changing this default level -->
<!-- in old versions these attributes might not be allowed
and in case (if they don't work) just ignore/skip them -->

<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
<httpCookies sameSite="None"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms ..... cookieSameSite="None" />
</authentication>

...
</system.web>
...
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
   <outboundRules>
    <!-- for old versions the only solution is to intercept/modify cookies -->

    <!-- Add "SameSite=None" to any cookie which does NOT have it yet -->
    <!-- currently this only works for secure https cookies -->
    <rule name="Add SameSite">
     <conditions>
      <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
      <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None" negate="true" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
     </conditions>
     <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
     <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None" />
    </rule>

    <!-- Add "Secure" to any cookie which does NOT have it yet, as long as it's HTTPS request or else a secure cookie would just be ignored -->
    <rule name="Add Secure">
     <conditions>
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; Secure" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
     </conditions>
     <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
     <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; Secure" />
    </rule>

    <!-- If samesite was set to none by cookieSameSite="None", -->
    <!-- remove it for non-https requests (currently only works for https) -->
    <rule name="No SameSite For HTTP">
     <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
     </conditions>
     <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="(.*);(\s*)SameSite=None" />
     <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}" />
    </rule>


   </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If you don't use the the `<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />` some newer ASP.NET Framework versions will by default render a `SameSite=Lax`. And if you just had the rewrite rules adding `SameSite=None` to all cookies you would get the SameSite attribute twice, which according to my tests work in SOME browsers like Chrome and Firefox (which will use the **last** occurrence of the SameSite attribute) but won't work in some like Edge (which uses the **first** occurrence of the attribute).

Since this first tag `<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />` will automatically set `SameSite=None` but will not automatically add `Secure` attribute, I've configured `SameSite=None` and `Secure` as independent rules. If I had it all in a single rule I would end up with duplicated attribute `SameSite=None`, which could break browsers (as explained above it's invalid and browsers may handle this inconsistently).

The `Secure` is only added if it's HTTPS request, so if you're still accepting HTTP connections your session cookies won't have the `Secure` added, which would make browsers ignore your cookie (and session wouldn't work at all). If you're behind a load balancer or reverse proxy you should use the [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791820/redirect-to-https-through-url-rewrite-in-iis-within-elastic-beanstalks-load-bal)

Last, there's a bug in [some versions of Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198181) in which the browser doesn't understand `SameSite=None` and treat it as `SameSite=Strict`. So for those specific versions you might decide not to render `SameSite=None`, although if not specified the default is still `SameSite=Lax` level, which might not be what you need (haven't found a solution for that).

Comment: It should be <system.webServer> not <system.web>

Comment: I am using .NET framework 4.6.1, it seems it is not marked as Secured yet even using the rewrite. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Michieru in localhost with http? Or in production with https? Secure is supposed to only work in HTTPS, that's why I added a restriction that secure is added only when HTTPS=TRUE. You can remove that rule if you want. For example if you're using a reverse proxy (which listens https but redirects to your IIS in http) you should remove it.

Comment: See solution for agent-specific setting here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357945/198953

Comment: For some reason I cannot get this working. IIS is automatically adding attribute SameSite=Lax to authentication cookie and the changes to web.config don't do anything on IIS version 10.0.14393.0. (Windows server 2016). However, with IIS 8.5.9600.16384 (Windows Server 2012 R2) these changes are working. What could be wrong? Could security update KB4537764 on Win Server 2016 affect this? Help appreciated.

Comment: @MarkkuRintala have you added `<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. After some more searching in the internet I found this: https://port135.com/2020/02/13/changes-to-the-samesite-cookie/. There writer suggested to add cookieSameSite="None" also to <authentication mode="Forms">. That worked for me. That article gives also essential information on latest Windows updates that are related to the SameSite cookie. Maybe I should write a new answer or you @drizin could update yours.

Comment: @MarkkuRintala I've just updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that saved my life.

Comment: Worked for me, Thank you! In the second section of rules, the add-statements are not inside a <conditions> block.

Comment: @drizin it is still not working : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71766217/asp-net-webforms-application-cookies-are-not-working-anymore-within-canvas-fac